# Can I disable a View component in react native?

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-native, reactjs-native

My app screen has a View component with few Text Inputs. I cannot disable text inputs. Is there a way that I can disable complete View?

P.S.: By Disabling a View component I mean that the component renders but becomes unresponsive of any action.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use [`pointerEvents`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#pointerevents):

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  ...
</View>
```

This will make the view unresponsive to touch events.

You can use something like

> <View pointerEvents={myCondition ? 'none' : 'auto'}>

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Comment: Can we give it conditinally?

Comment: Yes you can use something like `<View pointerEvents={myCondition ? 'none' : 'auto'}>`

Comment: super useful prop, how i never heard of it?

Comment: thanhks, this is quickly.

Answer (score 29):

Adding to Kerumen's answer, in some rare cases:

```
<View pointerEvents={myCondition ? 'none' : 'auto'}>
  ...
</View>
```

You might need to wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
<View pointerEvents={() => myCondition ? 'none' : 'auto'}>
  ...
</View>
```

Comment: It looks like your code block didn't format the way you intended. Also, in what rare cases would you need to wrap* it in an anonymous function?

Comment: honestly, I don't but for some reason, it didn't work until I warp it in a function, I am investigating to find out the reason

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Create a TouchableOpacity in a space where you want to make it unresponsive to any action.
like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{ width : 40 , height : 40}} activeOpacity={1}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

this area doesnt have any action from parents component